# Refer to self with CSS selector when binding dynamic elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code is used to bind events to dynamic elements with jQuery.

The `#selfID` element has `body` as its parent.

However, `body` has multiple children besides `#selfID`.

The goal is to narrow the binding and only bind to `mousedown` events of `#selfID` and any of its children with `childClass1` and `childClass2` as classes. (Siblings of `#selfID` may also have `childClass1` and `childClass2` children.)

`#selfID` is static and not created dynamically.

Thus, the code works for dynamically created `childClass1` and `childClass2` elements, but it doesn't work for `mousedown` events on `#selfID` itself.

Can `#selfID` refer to itself in the selector statement? Otherwise, it seems like the only other option is to create a separate binding statement just for `#selfID`?

```
  $("#selfID").on("mousedown", ".childClass1, .childClass2, #selfID", function(event) {
        // Do stuff
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> A selector string to filter **the descendants of the selected elements** that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

Since `#selfID` is static, you can try to use a parent element like below:

```
$("#selfID").parent().on("mousedown", "#selfID .childClass1,#selfID .childClass2, #selfID", function(event) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

So you do the logic on an upper element where you can add the needed element.

```js
$("#selfID").parent().on("mousedown", "#selfID .someclass, #selfID", function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('target');
  event.stopPropagation()
});
```

```css
#selfID {
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.someclass {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
.target {
  border:5px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selfID">
  <div class="someclass"></div>
</div>

<div class="someclass"></div>
```

We can optimize it by adding a condition inside the function to be able to reduce the selector:

```js
$("#selfID").parent().on("mousedown", ".someclass1,.someclass2, #selfID", function(event) {
  if($(this).closest('#selfID').length) {
    $(this).toggleClass('target');
    event.stopPropagation()
  }
});
```

```css
#selfID {
  background:red;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
}
.someclass1 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
.someclass2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
}
.target {
  border:5px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selfID">
  <div class="someclass1"></div>
  <div class="someclass2"></div>
</div>

<div class="someclass1"></div>

<div class="someclass2"></div>
```

Comment: thanks this is probably the best approach. unfortunately, it means #selfID needs to get repeated when choosing childClass1 and childClass2, which is not ideal but seems unavoidable. thanks again!

Comment: @Crashalot yes I think it's unavaoidable too but let's wait for some JS guru, there is probably some magic tricks ;)

Comment: yes waiting for other answers, that's why you didn't receive credit yet. thanks for your help!

Comment: @Crashalot I added a small improvement ;)

Comment: just saw it, will reply now and delete these comments! thanks.